# Функция внутри ajax поля data

Tags: javascript, ajax

Как сделать так, чтобы data в ajax запросе поступала из функции?

```
     function user_id(){
        $.get(
            pathLogin, 
            {email: email, pass: pass},
            function (data) {
              //
              return user_id;
            }); 
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: server+"php/photo.php",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      data: {id: user_id()},

      success: function (data) {
      //
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert("error");
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как аякс работает асинхронно, в данном случаи самым простым вариантом будет использовать колбеки, тоесть выполнить первый аякс, получить наш параметр(`user_id`) и на обработчике успешного выполнения первого запроса, вызывать 2рой, передавая в него нужные данные

```js
// call function
user_id(secondAjax)

function user_id(cb) {
  $.get(
    pathLogin, {
      email: email,
      pass: pass
    },
    function(data) {
      if (typeof cb === 'function')
        cb.call(this, data.user_id)
    });
}

function secondAjax(userId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: server + "php/photo.php",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    data: {
      id: userId
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert("error");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Проверьте, должно работать

```
function user_id(){
    $.get(
        pathLogin, 
        {email: email, pass: pass},
        function (data) {
          //
          return user_id;
        }); 
}

var myID = user_id();

$.ajax({
  url: server+"php/photo.php",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  data: {id: myID},

  success: function (data) {
  //
  },
  error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert("error");
  }
});
```

Поясню: мы не можем выполнить ajax запрос внутри ajax запроса. Поэтому мы сначала вызовем первую функцию, записав её значение в переменную myID *(её можно как угодно назвать, я назвал myID)*. В последствии, отправляя ajax запрос, в параметр id мы передаём эту переменную *(а точнее её значение)*, и всё работает. PROFIT.

**НО:** 
P.S.: *в функции user_id() присутствуют переменные* pathLogin, email, pass *значение которых должно быть указано до описанного кода, в **противном** случае функция работать не будет.*

Comment: ваш вариант к сожалению, работать не будет, так как функция `user_id` не возвращает ничего, можно конечно сделать гет синхронным, и немного подправив ваш код, он тоже заработает